# Перевести результат sql запроса в переменную

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Пишу бота на `aiogram` и использую базу данных `sqlite`.
Решил создать админ-панель, но столкнулся с тем, что не понимаю как присвоить переменной результат sql запроса

Вот сам sql запрос:

```
def adm_check(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT IsAdm FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
        result = self.cursor.fetchmany(1)
        if result:
            return int(result[0][0])
```

Comment: Так, и что - эта функция не возвращает результат или что? Код выглядит более-менее нормально.

Comment: @CrazyElf Все верно. Мне нужно присвоить переменной результат этой функции.

Comment: Покажите код, где вы хотите получить эту переменную, в каком месте

Comment: @CrazyElf Переменная бинарна. Если = 1, то при /adm пустит в админ панель, иначе ничего не произойдет

Comment: Это не очень правильный подход, к слову. В `aiogram` есть фильтры проверяющие на админа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def adm_check(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        query = self.cursor.execute("SELECT IsAdm FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
        result = query.fetchone()
        if result:
            return int(result[0])
```

Comment: вообще-то `cursor.execute` неизвестно что возвращает по Python Database API Specification (PEP 249), я не проверял для sqlite3, но лучше его возврат не использовать.